# Nested sequence iteration in scala, zip

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-collections

I have the following case classes

```
case class Outer(outerId: Integer, outerName: String, innerSeq:Seq[Inner]) 
case class Inner(innerName:String, innerAge: Integer, innerId: Integer)
```

I created the following instances

```
val innerSeq1 = Seq(Inner("in10",10, 0),Inner("in11",11, 1), Inner("in12",12, 2))
val innerSeq2 = Seq(Inner("in20",10, 0),Inner("in21",11, 1), Inner("in22",12, 2))
val outerSeq = Seq(Outer(1, "out1", innerSeq1), Outer(2, "out2", innerSeq2 ))
```

My intent is to create 3 element 3-tuples like this, I am not sure if I can use Zip or what to elegantly do this(I know a map then a map can do the iteration but I am not clear how will I get the below kind of output)

I want a 3-tuple in the following format

`(name of outer, name of inner, id of inner)
Seq(
    (out1, in10, 0), (out1, in11, 1), (out1, in12, 2),
    (out2, in20, 0), (out2, in21, 1), (out2, in22, 2)
)`

Basically I want to while iterating over `outersequence`, want the triplets to be formed and get this flattened three tuplet output

Comment: So, you want one item for each outer, each one containing the triple of every inner, am I interpreting this correctly?

Comment: that is correct

Comment: curiousengineer, I wonder if there is something wrong with my updated answer. If there is - could you point out what works not as you wanted?

Comment: i just tick marked it :)

Comment: @curiousengineer, I've also added a for-comprehension-based way in case you prefer that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Originally I misread your question. What you really want can be achieve with `flatMap` and inner `map` like this:

```
outerSeq.flatMap(o => o.innerSeq.map(i => (o.outerName, i.innerName, i.innerId)))
```

If you prefer [for-comprehension](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html) it might be even easier:

```
val res = for (o <- outerSeq;
               i <- o.innerSeq)
    yield (o.outerName, i.innerName, i.innerId)
```

Comment: thanks. Which is more functional :)? I remember, internally, one gets compiled into another though!

Comment: @curiousengineer, yes as the linked article says for-comprehension is compiled to exactly the same code. As to which is more functional, I think it is a question of taste. I think for-comprehension in this specific case produces a simpler code with a more clear intent. However others are entitled to different opinion.